# I want to get the count of an empty xml file having only closing tag. Using count function. I want to get count as zero

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an xml payload as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data/>
```

While using `count(/Data)=0` to check whether the data is zero or not it is not giving me proper results.

Answer (score 1):

There is one Data element so `count(/Data)` is 1.

If you want to test whether the Data element has any children, test `count(/Data/*) = 0`.